# JavaFx control action

Tags: javafx, user-input

I have a JavaFx application with multiple buttons to click. At some point in the application it does not make sense to click some of them.

What is the best way to control when a certain action (i. e. Button pressed) should be allowed and when not?

Comment: Disable the `Buttons` that you don't want to be pressed.

Comment: Yeah sure. But this ends in a mess with a huge amount of if-else statements. Is there not a more general approach?

Comment: @Caduceus There's no reason for there to be a huge number of `if`-`else` statements to do this. You can bind the individual `disableProperty()` of the various buttons, or register multiple listeners with whatever properties the disable state depends on.